# Code to find position of number inside sorted array after selection sort isn't stable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexof, selection-sort

This code sorts the array after inserting another element and returns the index of the inserted element in the sorted array (the first position or lowest possible index needs to be returned).

CODE:

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  var sortedarr = sort(combinelists(arr, num).sort());
  var pos = [];
  for (i = 0; i < sortedarr.length; i++) {
    if (sortedarr[i] == num) {
      pos.push(i);
    }
  }
  return pos[0];
}

function combinelists(arr1, arr2) {
  var newarr = [];
  newarr.push(arr2);
  for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    newarr.push(arr1[i]);
  }
  return newarr;
}

function sort(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    return arr;
  } else {
    var l = arr.length / 2;
    var leftarr = arr.slice(0, l);
    var rightarr = arr.slice(l);
    return combine(sort(leftarr), sort(rightarr));
  }
}

function combine(array, another_array) {
  var result = [];
  while (array.length && another_array.length) {
    if (array[0].age <= another_array[0].age) {
      result.push(array.shift());
    } else {
      result.push(another_array.shift());
    }
  }

  while (array.length)
    result.push(array.shift());

  while (another_array.length)
    result.push(another_array.shift());
  return result;
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([2, 20, 10], 19));
console.log(getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15));
```

But it doesn't seem to work for all inputs:

```
It works for the following tests: 
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 30
[40, 60], 50
[2, 20, 10], 19

But it doesn't work for these:
[2, 5, 10], 15
[5, 3, 20, 3], 5
[3, 10, 5], 3
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35
```

What's broken?

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: There is a [Code Review stack exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Jesus guys, yes I have a question - why is it working for some and not others?? Btw, "If it doesn't pass all the tests, its not ready for review on code review". So, yea..

Comment: That code seems quite complicated

Comment: Well thats what I thought too. Anyways, turns out simply using .sort() is better than building your own. Anyways, it's been fun all. 'ta 'ta..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without `compareFunction`, that means you get a result which every element is treated as string and not as number. That results, probably, to the wrong index.

```
var sortedarr = sort(combinelists(arr,num).sort());
//                                         ^^^^^^
```

You coud use a callback like

```
var sortedarr = sort(combinelists(arr,num).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; }));
```

for sorting by numbers.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if you caught it but, the sorting algorithm I had created seems to be messing with `Array#sort()`. I disconnected the selection sort and reverted to simply `.sort(...).` And it works. I'll accept your answer anyway, as it led me on the right path after all. Thanks :)